# UITableView On a ScrollView Bug

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a bug I can't seem to fix.
I have a tableview that displays Albums on the ipad. I can scroll the tableview if I touch and drag on the background(below the list) but not if I drag on the TableView Cells themselves.

I have an accessory button that does work on the table Cell.

Comment: Set userInteractionEnabled to NO on the cell.  It should go away.  The problem is that one of your views is intercept the scrollview's touches (most likely the button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
tableView.delaysContentTouches = YES;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
Could you explain why that fixed it?

Comment: Now that I looked into the docs I see that it is a Delay that delays handling the touch-down gesture until it can determine if scrolling is the intent